# set pagination pagenumber as default url

Tags: php, mysql, url, pagination

So i managed to build a working pagination system in php. But i want users to default to the first pagenumber of said pagination, so for example if somebody clicks on category 1 the URL will change to this `website.php?category=1` i would like this to be `website.php?category=1&pagenumber=1` as the default URL.

The reason why i want this is so i don't have to write 2 different query's: 1 if the category isset but no pagenumber, and 1 if both are set.

```
function getNews()
{
    // check if category is get via URL
    if (isset($_GET["category"]) && is_numeric($_GET["category"]) && intval($_GET["category"])) {
        // bind get category to categoryId
        $categoryId = intval($_GET["category"]);
        // if category is 1
        if ($categoryId == 1) {
            try {
                $db = new Connection();

                $database = $db->openConnection();

                if (isset($_GET["pagenumber"]) && is_numeric($_GET["pagenumber"]) && intval($_GET["pagenumber"])) {
                    $pageNumber = intval($_GET["pagenumber"]);

                    $itemsPerPage = 9;

                    $offset = ($pageNumber - 1) * $itemsPerPage;

                    $stm = $database->query("SELECT * FROM blog where blog.Categoryid = $categoryId LIMIT 9 OFFSET $offset ");

                    $stm->execute();

                    $rowNews = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    $totalItems = $database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog where blog.Categoryid = $categoryId")->fetchColumn();

                    $totalPages = intval(ceil($totalItems / $itemsPerPage));

                    $previousButton = ($pageNumber + 1) - $totalPages;

                    $nextButton = ($pageNumber) * $totalPages;

                    $pageIndex = 0;
```

this is what i currently have(i cut out the pagination system, can paste it in if needed).

//

this is how i generate my category select

```
<?php
        if (isset($_GET["category"])){
        $db = new Connection();

        $categoryId = $_GET["category"];

        $database = $db->openConnection();

        $stm = $database->query("SELECT * FROM category");

        $stm->execute();

        $fetchCategory = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach ($fetchCategory as $cats) {
            ?>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog.php?category=<?php echo $cats["categoryid"]; ?>"><?php echo $cats["categorytitle"]; ?></a>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        }else{
            $categoryId = 1;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>


<?php
$categoryId = -1;

if (isset($_GET["category"]) && intval($_GET["category"])) {
    $categoryId = intval($_GET["category"]);
    switch ($categoryId) {
        case 1:
            // do query for category id 1
            getNews();
            break;
        case 2:
            // do query for category id 2
            getEwarehouse();
            break;
        case 3:
            // do query for category id 3
            getPartners();
            break;
        default:
            ifnotNumeric();
            break;
    }
} else {
    ifnotSet();
}
?>
```

Some more general information:

1. Running laragon 4.0.15 with PHP 7.3.9
2. Using HeidiSQL 10.2.0.5599
3. Using PHPStorm 2019.2.2

if you need anymore code examples i can paste them in.

Comment: `if ( ! isset($_GET["pagenumber"]) ) { $pageNumber = 1; }`

Comment: Or `$pageNumber  = $_GET['pagenumber'] ?? 1;` in PHP >= 7

Comment: Where i would put this check ? i put an else after the check for the `if(isset($_GET[pagenumber]))` but it does not replace anything in the URL